# How to Get old Values In Other Object By using Trigger

Tags: trigger

Hi Sir I have Trigger Task
Once I Change The My Contact Email And Phone Number And After How To get my Old Email Id In Other Object Send Me code Any One

Comment: What have you tried so far? This site is not to just give you code for a scenario that is not even described clearly. What are you trying to do with the trigger?

Answer (score 2):

The generic pattern for accessing the old value is this:

```
trigger MyTrigger on Contact (before update) {
    for (Contact c : Trigger.new) {
        Contact old = Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
        String oldEmail = old.Email;
        String newEmail = c.Email;
        ...
    }
}
```